# Dataflow - how to create a PCollectionView to use with DoFnTester?

Tags: unit-testing, google-cloud-dataflow

This question is about Google Dataflow. I would like to test a do function with side inputs. The Google manuals list that you need code like this:

```
  static class MyDoFn extends DoFn<String, Integer> { ... }
  MyDoFn myDoFn = ...;
  DoFnTester<String, Integer> fnTester = DoFnTester.of(myDoFn);

  PCollectionView<List<Integer>> sideInput = ...;
  Iterable<Integer> value = ...;
  fnTester.setSideInputInGlobalWindow(sideInput, value);
```

I wonder how the code to create the PCollectionView instance looks like. When using DoFnTester you do not have a pipeline, and I do not see how to create PCollectionView instances without a pipeline. Can you tell me how to create a PCollectionView instance for use with DoFnTester?

Thanks for your time.

With kind regards,

Martijn Dirkse

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. You can just create a TestPipeline instance and use it to build the PCollectionView you need. It is no problem that the TestPipeline does not have any other purpose in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow 2.1 sdk sample [here](http://meethassan.net/2017/12/17/unit-testing-a-dataflow-apache-beam-pipeline-that-takes-a-side-input/) . There is no `setSideInputInGlobalWindow` in 2.X use `setSideInput` instead.